# Sqlcmd parameter passing to sql script file

Tags: batch-file, automation, parameter-passing, sqlcmd, sql-scripts

Is there a way to get a script file that will be executing via SQLCMD to accept the parms passed in the SQLCMD call.. i.e. I need to input the DbName variable from the user. Below is the code I am using to automate an sql script file through cmd.

```
sqlcmd -S %SName% -U %UName%  -P %Pwd%  -v DbName="%DbName%" -i D:\SqlScripts\script.sql
```

Also in my sql script file I am using $(DbName) to receive the passed variable. But it's not working.